# How can i learn CCNA using Ubuntu instead Windows OSs

Tags: 12.04, cisco

I just begin course of **CCNA** and i just notice that all work on **windows** ..

so my question have two parts first , can i learn and  training on ccna using linux /Ubuntu??

second . if yes, how can i use it and is there any changes in writing order and **cisco packet tracer**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GNS3 is a graphical network simulator that allows simulation of
> complex networks.
>
> To provide complete and accurate simulations, GNS3 is strongly linked
> with:
>
> - Dynamips, a Cisco IOS emulator.
> - Dynagen, a text-based front end for Dynamips.
> - Qemu, a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.
> - VirtualBox, a free and powerful virtualization software.
>
> GNS3 is an excellent complementary tool to real labs for network
> engineers, administrators and people wanting to study for
> certifications such as Cisco CCNA, CCNP, CCIP and CCIE as well as
> Juniper JNCIA, JNCIS and JNCIE.<sup>1</sup>

To install just click on the image below:

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[GNS3](http://www.gns3.net/)</sup>